# Stop highlighting text in NSTextField after pressing enter key (alt: jump to end of line)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, xcode11, swift5

I have a small macOS app in Swift 5. It's a simple calculator with a single line presented as an `NSTextField`. You type your math `expression` there (like: "34*12"), press the enter key and from your `String` you get a result - presented in the same `NSTextField`. So the user can go on calculating - just typing ahead *behind* the result, pressing enter again and so on.

I've been searching now literally for days and I can't find a solution to prevent the `NSTextField` from highlighting its content after the enter key is pressed.

Unfortunately I have not much of code to display because I simply don't know where to start.

`self.fileTextField.currentEditor()?.moveToEndOfDocument(nil)` just does nothing and other "workaround" things like fake-press the right-arrow-key result in permission issues in macOS:

```
let rightArrowKeyCode: UInt16 = 124
let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: rightArrowKeyCode, keyDown: true)
keyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
keyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)

let keyUpEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: rightArrowKeyCode, keyDown: false)
keyUpEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
keyUpEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
```

The code is short and simple (using Expression framework):

```
@IBOutlet weak var calcLine: NSTextField!

@IBAction func runCalc(_ sender: NSTextField) {

let stringValue = calcLine.stringValue
let expression = Expression(calcLine.stringValue)

do {
    result = try expression.evaluate()
    currentResult = result
    calcLine.stringValue = "\(result)"
   } catch {
     print("\(error)")
   }
}
```

I've tried loads of things I found (mostly) here but they seem very old and I've just started learning Swift for macOS apps.

Comment: The first line in this solution was something I had tried during the last days but not in combination with the second part. Would also be interesting to find out if ```location: 4``` can be something like „last“ oder „end“ etc. will try this soon, thank you.

Comment: Linked to another question. Here's my full solution:
Big thanks to @Willeke for his comment and the hint to the other question which led me to this simple solution: 

Calculate the number of characters in my result:

    `let resultLength = String(result).count`

Then use this number to set the `location` value of `NSRange` like this:

    `calcLine.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSRange(location: resultLength, length: 0)`

And finally call:

    `calcLine.displayIfNeeded()`

BTW: *calcLine* is my `NSTextField`